# angular 2 can't open dist/index.html after build?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When trying to deploy my Angular2 app. I need to test if build works fine.

I get empty page when trying to do so !

Is dist/index.html can be used to directly open the app using browser ?

Comment: No. It should be served by a web server.

Answer (score 3):

You have to deploy the content of your `dist/` dir to a web server (think *Caddy*, *nginx*, *Apache*, etc.).

Then you can test the app got built ok.

Comment: why it doesn't work by double clicking index.html since it's just html/css/js ?

Comment: @Cleancoder: I guess, it's due to *AJAX* calls using HTTP - your local files would use `file://`. There also might be problems related to the paths in app.

Answer (score 2):

in linux

1. Open the terminal, address to `src/dist` path
2. type `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
3. Open your browser and type `localhost:8000`